# Best way to store a collection of objects

Tags: objective-c

I have several objects that I want to store in an array. What is the way to do this in objective-c? I have been looking into NSMutableDictionary but have had no luck.

In my code below, I am iterating through an array of strings, making a network call for each string, and getting an object back for each string.  I want to store my objects in a list that I can access later.

```
-(void) setPictures {

    for(id item in self.phraseWordsArray) {

    AFNetworkingAPIClient *netowrkingObject = [[AFNetworkingAPIClient alloc] init];
    [netowrkingObject getPhotoForWord:item success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responseObject=%@",responseObject);
        self.test = responseObject;
        [self printOutJSON];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
    }];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `NSMutableArray` is what you need, am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your response objects into an `NSMutableArray` that is a property on the UIViewController calling this code, or elsewhere. See the following for an example scenario:

```
// In your interface...

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *responseObjects;

// ... Later in code

self.responseObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

- (void)setPictures {
  for(id item in self.phraseWordsArray) {

  AFNetworkingAPIClient *netowrkingObject = [[AFNetworkingAPIClient alloc] init];
  [netowrkingObject getPhotoForWord:item success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject=%@",responseObject);
    self.test = responseObject;
    [self printOutJSON];
    if (responseObject) {
       [self.responseObjects addObject:responseObject];
    }
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
  }];
 }   
}
```